# How to return python sum values from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created a dictionary of keys and values,letters each with its own `value`. Like below:

```
num = {
    'a': '1',
    'b': '2',
    'c': '3',
    'd': '4',
    'e': '5',
    'f': '6',
    'g': '7',
    'h': '8',
    'i': '9',
    'j': '10',
    'k': '11',
    'l': '12',
    'm': '13',
    'n': '14',
    'o': '15',
    'p': '16',
    'q': '17',
    'r': '18',
    's': '19',
    't': '20',
    'u': '21',
    'v': '22',
    'w': '23',
    'x': '24',
    'y': '25',
 'z': '26'}
```

I want to take in user input inform of word of . e.g trees`.

Then break it down the into individual `letters`. Refer to my `dictionary` then return sum of  its values  according to the dictionary.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? You want code? Then you should supply what you are able to do on your own.

Comment: @brayo: If you like my answer you can accept this.

Comment: No reason to have dictionary with string values of ints as the values. In fact, you could do import string; dictionary = { k:i for i, k in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)}

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like:

```
num = {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'10','k':'11','l':'12','m':'13','n':'14','o':'15','p':'16','q':'17','r':'18','s':'19','t':'20','u':'21','v':'22','w':'23','x':'24','y':'25','z':'26'}
name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
L = list(name)

print sum([int(num[i]) for i in L])
```

Input:

```
Enter name: mary
```

Output:

```
57
```

Comment: No need for brackets inside sum, it can take a genexp

Comment: @dwanderson: I use python 2.7.9 IDE. Without brackets, it's return error.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
di = {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'10','k':'11','l':'12', 'm':'13','n':'14','o':'15','p':'16','q':'17','r':'18','s':'19','t':'20','u':'21','v':'22','w':'23','x':'24','y':'25' ,'z':'26'}
p = raw_input()
l = map(int, [di[x] for x in p])
print sum(l)
```

Comment: Couldn't you supply a genexp to map?

Answer (score 0):

```
l = list(input)
print sum([int(num[i] for i in l])
```

Comment: While this does appear to solve the OP's problem, it would be even better if you added some explanation to help the OP and others with similar questions understand why this works, and how they can apply it to their own problems.

Comment: No need for brackets inside the sum, it can also take a genexp